# How to show domain value is default in combobox using C++ Win32 API?

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog, window

i am using C++ Win32 API.

i have a logondialogbox.its have a username textbox,password textbox,domainname combobox.

when i start the system,how can i show the domainname in combobox default?

in example:

raja is systemname
techserve is domainname

i already tried

`ComboBox_SetCurSel(GetDlgItem(_hwnd, IDC_COMBO), 1);`

But in other users like,

udhay is systemname
techserve is domainname

it shows systemname,that is udhay.

So,How can show techserve(domainname) is default value for Combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ComboBox_SelectString instead, it will update the edit control to show the item is selected

Answer (score 0):

Hm, may be problem is in indexing? First item have index *0*, not *1*.

Comment: @ Axilles:ya,i want domain name to show default even its placed in index 0 or 1.how can achieve it?